# Center of a $2$-Sylow

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Here we go for the last time with the group $G=GL_2(\mathbb F_3)$.

We know that it has three $2$-Sylow subgroups. So let $P\in\operatorname{Syl}_2(G)$.

I was searching for its center but I don't know where to start.
The only thing I noticed is that since $P$ is a $2$-group then $Z(P)\neq1$. Moreover since $Q_8<P$ then $P$ can't be abelian, hence $Z(P)<P$. Hence $|Z(P)|\in\{2,4,8\}$. But $P$ contains al least $6$ subgroup of order $4$ and $4$ subgroups of order $8$. So I'm a little bit lost.

**EDIT** I know that $P$ has $1$ element of order $1$, one central involution $-\mathbb I$ and $4$ non-central involutions (hence $5$ element of order $2$), $6$ elements of order $4$ and $4$ elements of order $8$. From this I deduced that $P$ has *at least* $6$ subgroups of order $4$ and $4$ subgroups of order $8$. If I prove (for example) that there are no other groups of such orders ($8$ and $4$) then observing that $-\mathbb I$ must stay in $Z(P)$ I could deduce something.

Can someone help me please? Thanks a lot

Comment: Its center consists precisely of the scalar matrices (eg by Schur's Lemma), since the Sylow 2-subgroup is absolutely irreucible).

Comment: Thanks a lot but I can't use the Schur's Lemma! Have you got any other idea?

Comment: If you want to swat this fly with a cannonball, then you can use Skolem-Noether theorem to tell that if you fix a copy of $\Bbb{F}_9$ in $M_2(\Bbb{F}_3)$, then its Frobenius automorphism (of order two) can be realized by conjugating with a matrix $A$. Restricting this to $C=\Bbb{F}_9^*=\Bbb{F}_9\cap GL_2$ you have a cyclic group of order 8 such that conjugation by $A$ = cubing in $C$. The center consists necessarily of the fixed points of that conjugation, i.e. $\Bbb{F}_3^*$.

Comment: You don't need to quote Schur's Lemma. I was just giving a hint and a justification. You know that $P$ is non-Abelian. One subgroup $M$ of order $8$ is cyclic (and normal),so $Z(P) \leq M$ and $Z(P)$ is cyclic.Now $Z(Q_{8})$ is cyclic of order $2$ and $Z(Q_{8}) \leq M.$  Also, $Q_{8} \cap M$ is cyclic of order $4$, and is not even central in $Q_{8},$ so you should be able to go from there.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson:first of all thanks. Then: taken $a\in P$ of order $8$ we have that $\langle a\rangle\le P$ is a cyclic subgroup of order $8$, hence it has index $2$ and so it's normal in $P$. But how can we deduce from this that $Z(P)\le M$? Many thanks

Comment: Well, otherwise $Z(P)M >M$, so $P = MZ(P),$ which is Abelian, and you know $P$ isn't.